# Travel to and from Canada with temporary resident visa

Tags: canada

i'm on a work permit in Canada and my temporary resident visa (TRV) is valid until 2019 April 20. I'm applying for a work permit extension and also a TRV extension. It might take a while for it to get approved. I will be on implied status until then and won't be able to travel to and from Canada.

So I'm thinking of taking a week's vacation in mid-March while I still have valid TRV and work permit. Will it be a problem while entering Canada with the TRV  expiring in one month? Is there any rule that I should have six months validity on my TRV when entering Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Canada temporary resident visas work similarly to the US visitor visas, in that the visa expiration date is the last date you may enter Canada using the visa.

Because your visa (and presumably work permit) will be valid when you re-enter Canada, you will have no problems entering.

Note that Canada now also requires that passports be valid; Canada no longer issues visas with expiration dates later than the passport expiration date. If your passport is near to expiration, you may wish to renew the passport before obtaining a new visa.